# How to add indexing to auth_user model django

Tags: python, django

I want to add index to Django built-in table for users which is auth_user. I want to add index to first_name of auth_user model.

How can i do it?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user

Comment: If you want to index a field in your model, check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index In your case you need to read about customizing the user model see @klasske link.  You may want to look at proxy models.  I've never used them, but it looks like that might work

Answer (score 1):

You can create an index directly into the database.
For example (PostgreSQL):

```
CREATE INDEX auth_username_idx ON username (auth_user);
```

It should work.